# Power Automate: How to build a flow so that whenever I update an excel file in sharepoint, a sharepoint list is updated

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Hi so I want to make a change log in sharepoint.

This requires me to have two Sharepoint Lists: The Change Log and a Master List that houses all IDs, folder names and project names of the individual projects.

The Master List and the Change Log are linked so that when I choose a Project in the Change Log and then change said Project in the master List, the info is also changed in the change log.

However I can´t manually update the Master List in Sharepoint because of other software I use and therefore I have a Master List Excel sheet. So here is my issue:

How do I make my master list mirror what I have in the Excel list? (e.g. when I add a row in the excel the same row is added in the master list; when i change a folder name in the excel, the name also changes in the master list)?

I have tried to build a flow that looks as follows:

[image]

So I think what the 'Code' does is compare line by line the contents of the master and the excel and then update those that were changed/add those that were there. But that is not what happens: It runns the code and NOTHING happens to my master list.

Comment: You’d need to show us more of the flow and highlight where you think it’s going wrong. Sorry but too hard to provide specific guidance as of right now.

Comment: Unfortunately I am a complete beginner so I really don´t know where stuff goes wrong. I am not attached to my solution so if you have a better one i am all ears (especially since mine doesn´t do anything). 'My uneducated guess is that it doesnt recognise the rows it needs to compare... but idk